# changing autoconf version on a linux server

Tags: linux, autoconf, automake

I need to run a program on a linux machine, and the only one I have access to is my university's server with (for some reason) outdated versions of autoconf and automake. My program needs more recent versions. I have the most recent versions of each on the server in my home directory, but can't install them  in /usr/local/bin since I'm not a root user. So I guess I have two questions:

1. How to get autoconf/automake to *install* somewhere in my home directory? Is this possible?
2. How to get a program to access these newer versions, instead of automatically calling the outdated ones?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 2 common solutions which have been mentioned are stow and just installing with `--prefix=$HOME` (some people like `--prefix=$HOME/usr`, if you use NFS mounted home directories `--prefix=$HOME/$(uname -m)` is handy.)  Another good choice is to use pkgsrc and add/update your packages as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My preferred method for this is to use [GNU Stow](http://www.gnu.org/software/stow/) to manage packages in my home directory. You can use `$HOME` or `$HOME/usr` or whatever else. I think `$HOME/usr` is probably best, as it stops stow from having to walk all over your homedir.

So first you configure and install stow. Download and unpack it, then run something like:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr && make && make install prefix=$HOME/usr/stow/stow-2.2.0
```

Then you make stow stow itself:

```
$ cd ~/usr/stow
$ stow-2.2.0/bin/stow stow-2.2.0
```

Now you add `$HOME/usr/bin` to `$PATH`. Then you install autoconf. Unpack and cd into it, then run:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr && make && make install prefix=$HOME/usr/stow/autoconf-2.69
$ cd ~/usr/stow
$ stow autoconf-2.69
```

Why do I do this? it lets me easily remove a package from my home directory without causing massive headaches: `cd ~/usr/stow && stow -D autoconf-2.69`, for instance. I manage `/usr/local` in a similar fashion, but there I can get stow from apt, so there's no bootstrapping trouble.

Answer (score 2):

I don't remember for sure, but most likely both are autotools-based, so you can configure then using `./configure --prefix=${HOME}/autoprefix` and install.

Comment: Except that I suggest to use the same prefix for all the GNU software you'll need to install, so `./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr`  then add `$HOME/usr/bin`  in front of your `$PATH`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yeah, I normally use `$HOME/prefix` if I have to. Was just illustrating the technique.